# Dynamically circle created on span I need to hide with animation in click event

Tags: jquery, html

Circle created dynamically when I click on that circle that time circle down animation execute and hide that circle. Its working on key down but I don't know why its not working on onClick event.

May be its working with live() and delegate() but I don't know how...

Here is link for my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRJpEx

```js
function CircleDown(ch) {
  var keycode = ch.id;
  alert(keycode);
  var width = screen.width - 100;
  var height = screen.height - 200;
  $('.bubb' + keycode).animate({
    "top": height + "px",
    "opacity": 0
  }, 'slow');
  $('.bubb' + keycode).fadeOut('slow').hide('slow', function() {
    code += 20;
    $('#score').html(code);
    $(this).remove();
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Getting screen resolutions and positioning the start button
  var width = screen.width - 100;
  var height = screen.height - 200;
  var code = 0;
  $('#start').css({
    "top": (height / 2) + 'px',
    "left": (width / 2) + 'px'
  });

  $('#start').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#score').show();
    genLetter();
  });

  // Dealing KeyEvents and fading out matched bubble
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode;
    $('.bubb' + keycode).animate({
      "top": height + "px",
      "opacity": 0
    }, 'slow');
    $('.bubb' + keycode).fadeOut('slow').hide('slow', function() {
      code += 20;
      $('#score').html(code);
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

  // Generating a random alphabet between A-Z
  function genLetter() {
      var color = randomColor();
      var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
      var ch = String.fromCharCode(k);
      var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
      var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
      $('body').append('<span id=' + ch + ' attrChar=' + ch + ' class="bubb bubb' + k + '" style="left: ' + left + '; top: ' + top + '; background-color:' + color + '" onclick=CircleDown(' + ch + ')>' + ch + '</span>');
      setTimeout(genLetter, 1000);
    }
    //$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    //console.log( $( this ).text() );
    //});
  $('#Round').click(function() {

    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#score').show();

  });

  // Generating a random color
  function randomColor() {
    var color = '';
    var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
    for (c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
      no = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
      color += values[no];
    }
    return color;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.bubb {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: bold 14px verdana;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}
#score {
  font-size: 46px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 50px;
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
}
#start {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 15px arial;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
#start:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score">0</div>
<div id="start">Start</div>
```

Comment: Eh, works for me in the snippet. ^^^ Check?

Comment: i want to hide that circle on click event..just like key down... like if circle having "s" and i press "s" key then its hide and down animation execute..that things i want execute on key event

Comment: @PraveenKumar use my link for keydown to see keydown animation its not working in snippet...i want to same animation on click event

Comment: Checking it....

Comment: thank u @PraveenKumar

Comment: **`#FAIL`** Sorry! `:(`

Comment: any suggestion for me? @PraveenKumar

Comment: I am really confused, Darshak. Let's leave for sometime and let someone answer this.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  i know why you are confused..bcoz all circle created in same position in  Codepen but in my pc its created dynamically in any position..with different color..but i dont know want its created same position in Codepen

Comment: You've got an answer that might be working.

Comment: thanks @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated code. onclick is working here for circle.

At onclick function there was problem of getting keycode.
So I have corrected it by using following:

```
var keycode = ch.id;
if(keycode!=undefined){
   keycode = keycode.charCodeAt(0);
}
```

```js
var code;
function CircleDown(ch) {
  var keycode = ch.id;
  if(keycode!=undefined){
   keycode = keycode.charCodeAt(0);
  }
  alert(keycode);
  var width = screen.width - 100;
  var height = screen.height - 200;
  $('.bubb' + keycode).animate({
    "top": height + "px",
    "opacity": 0
  }, 'slow');
  $('.bubb' + keycode).fadeOut('slow').hide('slow', function() {
    code += 20;
    $('#score').html(code);
    $(this).remove();
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Getting screen resolutions and positioning the start button
  var width = screen.width - 100;
  var height = screen.height - 200;
  var code = 0;
  $('#start').css({
    "top": (height / 2) + 'px',
    "left": (width / 2) + 'px'
  });

  $('#start').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#score').show();
    genLetter();
  });

  // Dealing KeyEvents and fading out matched bubble
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode;
    $('.bubb' + keycode).animate({
      "top": height + "px",
      "opacity": 0
    }, 'slow');
    $('.bubb' + keycode).fadeOut('slow').hide('slow', function() {
      code += 20;
      $('#score').html(code);
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });

  // Generating a random alphabet between A-Z
  function genLetter() {
      var color = randomColor();
      var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
      var ch = String.fromCharCode(k);
      var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
      var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
      $('body').append('<span id=' + ch + ' attrChar=' + ch + ' class="bubb bubb' + k + '" style="left: ' + left + '; top: ' + top + '; background-color:' + color + '" onclick=CircleDown(' + ch + ')>' + ch + '</span>');
      setTimeout(genLetter, 1000);
    }
    //$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    //console.log( $( this ).text() );
    //});
  $('#Round').click(function() {

    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#score').show();

  });

  // Generating a random color
  function randomColor() {
    var color = '';
    var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
    for (c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
      no = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
      color += values[no];
    }
    return color;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.bubb {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font: bold 14px verdana;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}
#score {
  font-size: 46px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 50px;
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
}
#start {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 15px arial;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
#start:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score">0</div>
<div id="start">Start</div>
```